# Definition of "From Currency" and "To Currency"?

Tags: fx

I'm using a service provider to access FX data, and when requesting the ticker `SWEUBOE` which is the Bank of England's exchange rate for EUR and CHF, I get the following meta information:

```
From Currency Swiss Franc 
To Currency   Euro
```

Yet the value of this rate for today(2017.03.16) is 1.0716 (EUR) which is clearly the other way round, i.e. it's from EUR to Swiss francs(i.e. 1 EUR = 1.0716 CHF).

Is the service provider giving me incorrect information or did I misunderstand something about the "from" and "to" currency?

Comment: In my personal opinion (FWIW) you are right. The From/To labels provided by the service provider appear to be incorrect or confusing.

Comment: @AlexC I think the provider is operating under the logic: How many CHF are needed to buy one EURO? Answer: 1.0716 CHF. Therefore from 1.0716 CHF I get ONE Euro.

Comment: @Roland I think you answered your own question. I was trying to figure this out and thought it could be a difference between quoting a price and quoting deal amounts, but I assume this is a price quote not a deal?

Comment: @rupweb It's an exchange rate not a specific deal, if that answers your question.

Comment: Among FX professionals this rate would be referred to as EURCHF, which is unambiguous and (once you are used to it) clear. The price of a unit of the base currency EUR is being expressed in the quote currency CHF.

Comment: @noob2 Yes, I'm appaled that this specific provider doesn't use a clear nomenclature.

Comment: Maybe the person who wrote the software was thinking along the lines of SWIFT. They use CurrencyBought and CurrencySold style information. The way a currency is quoted (or dealt) can be different from the perspective of a buyer or seller. Both parties are always buying and selling the opposite to each other.